# Showing error in password reset in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, passwords, reset

I have brand new laravel 5.8 installation in my htdocs
All the things of its default auth is working but when I tried password reset it gives me error 
It sends the reset email to the mail but when I click on the reset from mail it gives me this error

//
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost

//

Comment: What is the url you use to access your site locally and what is the url that has generated in the email?

Answer (score 0):

1.Activate **mod_rewrite**

```
 sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

2.Set **AllowOverride** directive to **all** in  vhost file

In you have not used virtual hosts then open **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf** find these 
block

```
 <Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Change **AllowOverride None**  to **AllowOverride all** as below

```
 <Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Just in case you are using virtual hosts then you’ll need to search for above code in /etc/apache2/sites-available/{somename}.conf

3.Restart apache

```
 sudo service apache2 restart
```